# How do I remove item lore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to make a GUI for my server, and there is an item I would really like to use, and that's the banner patterns, they look like scrolls which would really fit with the server. So when I tried to rename the item and change it's lore, the item lore from before still showed: [image]

Is there any way I can change this? Maybe an NBT tag I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 2):

Item lores are stored in the `display.Lore` tag of the item:

```
{
  display: {
    Name: '{"text":"Skills!"}',
    Lore: [
      '{"text":"Your Skills"}'
    ]
  }
}
```

The anvil can only edit the `Name` tag, but not the lore. You can use commands to edit the lore, such as:

```
give @s diamond_sword{display:{Lore:['"Text"']}}
```

It is possible to edit the item lore on items, but not while they're in a player's inventory. To do this, place your item in a chest, then run the following command:

```
data modify block <x> <y> <z> Items[0].tag.display.Lore set value ['"New Lore"']
```